# DataGrid Row Underlyings

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Hello I would like to know, if it is possible to make single row underlyings.

If you select a row in the DataGrid, the selected row gets like one or two new rows (underlyings) attached to the selected row with some information.

So every time you click on a row in DataGrid it will be kind of expanded and some new rows will be shown with more information

Hopefully, it will be possible!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this ain't possible with a Datagrid.

I did some research about it and I couldn't find any way that would let me use a 'parent-child' structure in a datagrid (atleast not with the default functionality). What I did find is this :
http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html

This is a listview, upgraded with columns. A listview can have a parent-child structure. So maybe you can have a look at this?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer!
I have just looked at your link, and it wasn't my way of doing it. I have seen the solution somewhere before, but I can't remember where.